# Split intersections of lines considering bridges and tunnels

Tags: routing, topology, network, splitting

I want to make a road network routable. I already have a road shapefile, but there are many intersections of lines that I want to split. Now I have two problems:

(1) My first approach to split them was to use the "split with lines" tool from QGIS. But the new shapefile contains empty attributes. I don't understand why. I changed the multi-part lines to single-part lines, but I still have the problem.

(2) Even if the "split with lines" tool would work, I have some bridges and tunnels. How can I exclude these from the split?

I am working with QGIS and ArcGIS (basic license). This is what my data looks like, which is from OpenStreetMap. The red circle shows an example where two roads cross, but the lines are not separated, even though the attribute table says they are neither bridges nor tunnels.
[image]

---

UPDATE:

I'll try to make my problem clearer. On the image below is my current network with bridges and tunnels from OSM. Some roads intersect and at most of these intersections the lines are split (red nodes). But some are not (see number 1 on the image). Now I want to split all these lines without splitting the lines over bridges or tunnels (number 2 on the image).

The lines have to be separated for my further work with the attribute table, because each line segment should contain different attributes. In the end, the network will contain information about road properties and more. In addition, it should be routable, which is why OSM is used as a data basis.
[image]

I found a solution for my first problem. Instead of "split with lines" I used the GRASS tool "v.clear". This is what happened. All intersections were separated, but but of course also at the bridges. Any ideas on how I can prevent this?
[image]

Comment: What does your data look like exactly? The splitting may or may not be necessary; the real issue is that, without proper attribution of over/underpasses in your data, you are looking at a tedious manual identification process.

Comment: I work with OSM data. I have two columns; one for tunnels and one for bridges. Unfortunately, the lines of the OSM data do not divide at all intersections. Even if neither tunnels nor bridges are there.

Comment: I found a solution with v.clean from GRASS but still have the problem what to do with tunnels and bridges.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the problem: in case of (visual only) pseudo-intersections where there in fact is no intersection (like bridges, tunnels), you want to tell the network that there is no connection between both lines - right? From my experience in QGIS: as long as you draw tow intersecting lines but without a common node, routing functions do not use this pseudo-intersection but consider it as two topologically un-connected lines.

Comment: Consider these lines, extracted form OSM with `key=highway`: the line running north/south is a bridge, the yellow highlighted road in E/W direction passes under the brdige. Bridge and yellow road are not connected, so automatically using `Shortest path (point to point)`, QGIS finds the (topologically correct) route that (if considered only visually) makes a detour: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w96sd.png

Comment: @Babel I hope the update above is helpful.The splitting of the lines is important because the individual segments will contain different data.

Comment: Can you make a selection by expression (based on your attributes for tunnels etc.) and the, when running `v.clean`, check the box next to `Selected features only`?

Comment: Thank you. The tip definitely helps. Unfortunately, the bridges and tunnel lines are missing in the output file. I could insert them with copy and paste, but a more efficient solution would be nice.

Comment: For the second step firstly use "Clip" or some tool that will leave you with lines that are not within your polygons representing tunnels and bridges. Then split the lines with this result shapefile of clip or some other tool you will use. Then you will not have intersections on bridges and tunnels :)